# Converting hex to int64 in PHP

Tags: php, math, conventions, number-formatting

How to convert hex `48ea369a4c120000` to 64bit integer `20120214104648` (little endian byte order) in PHP?

hexdec(), base_convert() and unpack() does not help.

See screenshot below.

[image: See screenshot below]

Comment: That decimal looks remarkably like a datetime (2012-02-14 10:46:48) - if it is, try converting it to a unix timestamp for transmission instead, this will produce numbers that are within the bounds of 32 bit until [2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) so you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 values of `48ea369a4c120000` if you consider [endiannes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

```
Little endian    =        20120214104648
Big endian       =   5254071951610216448
```

The little endian value of `48ea369a4c120000` can be calculated by following process.

```
$data="48ea369a4c120000";
$u = unpack("H*", strrev(pack("H*", $data)));
$f = hexdec($u[1]);
echo $f; // 20120214104648
```

**Note:** This is manually done as the endianness of the host is different. if the host had same endianness, only a single call to `hexdec` was enough.

Comment: 64bit int of 48ea369a4c120000(hex) must be 20120214104648. hexdec() does not convert to 64bit

Comment: @Antonix try it [here](http://www.statman.info/conversions/hexadecimal.html) and you get `5254071951610216448` as well.

Comment: @Antonix what is your PHP version, I see it works on my `PHP 5.3.2`

Comment: yes, im sure, in c++ that was ok, and 48ea369a4c120000 converted to  20120214104648

Comment: If you run [this code](http://pastie.org/3685567) in your computer and you see the expected output your compiler is 64-bit. If your compiler is not 64-bit you'll see truncated output.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [hexdec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php).

```
$integer = hexdec('48ea369a4c120000'); // $integer is now the decimal version of the number provided.
```

Note, however, that if the resultant number is outside the bounds than the platform's storage (e.g. 64 bits needed on a 32-bit platform) then you'll get a float, not an int.

Comment: 64bit int of 48ea369a4c120000(hex) must be 20120214104648. hexdec() does not convert to 64bit

Comment: @Antonix That's not true. Just google '0x48ea369a4c120000 in decimal' or type it into wolfram alpha..

Comment: 48ea369a4c120000 is only 20120214104648 if you're working with unsigned integers, which PHP does not support. hexdec() does support 64-bit integers, if the platform it's running on supports it.