# Increment hex value (little endian?) in PHP

Tags: php, integer, hex, increment

In an incoming UDP packet I have the hex value `b70500`. This is actually a sequence number (`1463`). I need to increment this value before sending it back to the server in the same format (`b80500`).

[image]

How can I, in PHP, increment the value by one?

Using the code suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908743/converting-hex-to-int64-in-php) I was able to convert the hex value to an integer and increment it by one:

```
$original_hex = 'b70500';                                        // 1463
$original_int = unpack("H*", strrev(pack("H*", $original_hex))); // 0005b7
$incremented_int = hexdec($original_int[1]) + 1;                 // 1464
$incremented_hex = ?                                             // Expected result: b80500
```

... But I have no idea how to convert it back into hex. Perhaps there is a more efficient method?

Comment: You use `unpack` to get the decimal number, check out `pack` (http://php.net/manual/de/function.pack.php) method for the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty and I bet there are more efficient ways of doing this, but it works:

```
function increment_hex($hex) {
  $original_hex = $hex;
  $original_int = unpack("H*", strrev(pack("H*", $original_hex)));
  $incremented_int = hexdec($original_int[1]) + 1;
  $incremented_hex = dechex($incremented_int);

  $padded_hex = str_pad($incremented_hex, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $reversed_hex = unpack("H*", strrev(pack("H*", $padded_hex)));

  return $reversed_hex[1];
}

echo "result: " . increment_hex('b70500') . "\n";
```

`result: b80500`

Answer (score 2):

`hexdec()` and `dechex()`. You do not have to unpack the value.

```
$incremented = dechex(hexdec('b70500') + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, that snippet returns `b70501`, (which corresponds to 67000). The expected result is `b80500` (1464). To be more specific: The server expects the number in the same format, `5b8` (which also corresponds to 1464 won't do ...).